# Not to forward certain email Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have set up a rule to forward incoming emails from Outlook to my Gmail account. The problem is that certain mails in which I'm a CC (about 1000/day monitoring system running status) are also forwarded to my Gmail and fill up my account very quickly.

I have set up rules in Outlook to move those emails to a certain folder (called Monitored_Emails), but I don't know how to filter those emails so they don't forward to Gmail.

How can I set this rule to forward all emails except those in a certain folder name?

Comment: Outlook rules have Except conditions - did you try these?
The order of Outlook rules matters, so make sure they are executed in the right order.
If you really want help here, edit your question and show your rule definitions and order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up a new rule with the exception with particular words such as 'New Application', which is fixed words, not to be forwarded.

But I still no ideas how to skip the forwards rule for specific email folder emails not to be forwards.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the steps below? 
This should accomplish what you're looking for as far as keeping the `cc` emails from being forwarded to your gmail account. Your options may be slightly different if you use a version newer than 2003.

- Create a blank rule
- Check - `where my name is in the To box`
- If that is true, set it to Forward the email to your gmail account
- Check  - `except where my name is in the cc box`